Derive relation between slopes of a quadrilateral with vertices on a parabola using analog of Laguerre formula?
A conic section $\cal C$ intersects the infinity line at two points $I_1,I_2$.
Let $A_1(x_1,y_1),A_2(x_2,y_2)$ be two fixed points on $\cal C$, let $A(x,y)$ be a moving point on $\cal C$, let the lines $AA_1,AA_2$ intersect the infinity line at $P_1,P_2$, then the cross-ratio $(I_1,I_2,P_1,P_2)$ is constant.
Example 1.
If $\cal C$ is a rectangular hyperbola $xy=1$, the two points $I_1,I_2$ have homogeneous coordinates $(1,0,0),\ (0,1,0)$.
Using this property to derive relation between slopes of a quadrilateral with vertices on $\cal C$:
$(I_1,I_2,P_1,P_2)=\text{const}\implies\dfrac {y-y_{1}}{x-x_{1}}\cdot\dfrac {x-x_{2}}{y-y_{2}}=\text{const}$
Example 2.
If $\cal C$ is a circle, the two points $I_1,I_2$ have homogeneous coordinates $(1,i,0),\ (1,-i,0)$.
Using this property to derive relation between slopes of a quadrilateral with vertices on $\cal C$:
$(I_1,I_2,P_1,P_2)=\text{const}\implies\measuredangle A_1AA_2=\text{const}$

Question:
If $\cal C$ is a parabola $y=x^2$, the two points $I_1,I_2$ are the same, can we still use this property to derive relation between slopes of a quadrilateral with vertices on a parabola?
I think it is necessary to see a parabola as a limit of hyperbola.

Is it possible to derive $\dfrac{y-y_{1}}{x-x_{1}}-\dfrac{y-y_{2}}{x-x_{2}}=\text{const}$ from $(I_1,I_2,P_1,P_2)=\text{const}$?

For those who don't know Laguerre formula : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_formula

$y=x^2$ is the limit of the hyperbola
$\mathcal{C}_e:x^2+\left(y-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2-e^2 \left(y+\frac{1}{4}\right)^2=0$ as $e\to1$.
$\mathcal{C}_e$ intersects the line at infinity at $I_{1,2}=(1,\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^2-1}},0)$.
$P_1=(1,\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1},0),P_2=(1,\frac{y-y_2}{x-x_2},0)$.
$$(I_1,I_2,P_1,P_2)=\frac{\left(\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^2-1}}\right)\left(\frac{y-y_2}{x-x_2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^2-1}}\right)}{\left(\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^2-1}}\right) \left(\frac{y-y_2}{x-x_2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^2-1}}\right)}$$
Taking the limit $e\to1$,
$$\lim_{e\to1}(I_1,I_2,P_1,P_2)=1$$
From $(I_1,I_2,P_1,P_2)=\text{const}$ we get $1=\text{const}$, which is not helpful.
Taking the coefficient of lowest order term of $(I_1,I_2,P_1,P_2)-1$ as $e\to1$,
$$\lim_{e\to1}\frac{(I_1,I_2,P_1,P_2)-1}{\sqrt{e^2-1}}=\lim_{e\to1}\frac{\frac{\left(\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^2-1}}\right)\left(\frac{y-y_2}{x-x_2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^2-1}}\right)}{\left(\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^2-1}}\right) \left(\frac{y-y_2}{x-x_2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^2-1}}\right)}-1}{\sqrt{e^2-1}}=-2\left(\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}-\frac{y-y_2}{x-x_2}\right)$$
this agrees with the result $\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}-\frac{y-y_2}{x-x_2}=\text{const}$
